# Source for the Saying 'Sometimes People with the Worst Past Create the Best Future' attributed to Umar ibn al-Khattab (RA)

Tags: reference-request

I came across the saying "Sometimes people with the worst past create the best future" attributed to Umar ibn al-Khattab (RA), but I couldn't find a specific source for this quote. Can someone provide the original source or reference in which book or text Umar ibn al-Khattab (RA) is documented to have said this?